# How can I calculate standard deviation in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using norway_new_car_sales_by_model.csv [Dataset here](https://www.kaggle.com/dmi3kno/newcarsalesnorway/data) dataset which you find. I want to find the model that has highest sales fluctuation over the years. I am using standard deviation of the yearly total sales for each model. 
Expected output is: 
[image: Expected output]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

 data=pd.read_csv("norway_new_car_sales_by_model.csv",header=None,encoding="latin-1")
 data.columns = ['Year','Month','Make','Model','Quantity','Pct']#give column name
 data.drop(data.head(1).index, inplace=True) #drop first row
 data[['Quantity']]=data[['Quantity']].astype(np.int64)
 data.dropna(subset=['Quantity'], how='all', inplace = True)


 maketotal_1 = data.pivot_table(values='Quantity',index=['Month','Model','Make'],aggfunc=np.std)
```

My question are that

1) I did not handle nan values... even if i try many codes...

[image: My output]

2) How to get Audi A4 Audi from Index column

Comment: Can you add data sample to question?

Comment: Can you paste data as text, not images? Images cannot be copied into an interpreter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

First remove parameter `header=None` from `read_csv`, because first in csv are columns names:

```
data=pd.read_csv("norway_new_car_sales_by_model.csv",encoding="latin-1")
print (data.head())
   Year  Month         Make              Model  Quantity   Pct
0  2007      1  Volkswagen   Volkswagen Passat      1267  10.0
1  2007      1      Toyota         Toyota Rav4       819   6.5
2  2007      1      Toyota      Toyota Avensis       787   6.2
3  2007      1  Volkswagen     Volkswagen Golf       720   5.7
4  2007      1      Toyota      Toyota Corolla       691   5.4
```

Apply `pivot_table` function with `np.std`:

```
maketotal_1=data.pivot_table(values='Quantity',index=['Month','Model','Make'],aggfunc=np.std)
print (maketotal_1.head())
                          Quantity
Month Model       Make            
1     Audi A3     Audi   50.986109
      Audi A4     Audi   60.549704
      Audi A6     Audi         NaN
      Audi Q3     Audi         NaN
      BMW 2-serie BMW          NaN
```

Last first remove `NaN`s by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert `MultiIndex` to columns and create unique default index:

```
df1 = maketotal_1.dropna().reset_index()
```

Last per groups by `Make` get indices of max values by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and then select rows by `loc`:

```
df3 = df1.loc[df1.groupby('Make')['Quantity'].idxmax()]
print (df3)
     Month              Model            Make    Quantity
447     12            Audi A3           Audi   119.867427
415     11             BMW i3            BMW   460.936366
56       2        Ford Mondeo           Ford   169.889880
235      6         Honda CR-V          Honda   171.579671
457     12       Hyundai ix35        Hyundai    32.526912
348      9       Kia Sportage            Kia    55.154329
60       2         Mazda CX-5          Mazda   144.030957
14       1  Mercedes-Benz GLC  Mercedes-Benz   119.501046
160      4     Mitsubishi ASX     Mitsubishi   312.541197
391     10        Nissan Leaf         Nissan   225.322584
114      3         Opel Astra           Opel    85.182158
22       1        Peugeot 207        Peugeot    97.962578
168      4        Renault Zoe        Renault    53.740115
395     10      Skoda Octavia          Skoda   121.668767
122      3      Suzuki Vitara         Suzuki    85.559921
123      3      Tesla Model S          Tesla   510.400823
33       1     Toyota Corolla         Toyota   326.683333
179      4    Volkswagen Golf     Volkswagen   454.872681
485     12          Volvo V40          Volvo   183.919366
```

EDIT:

There is no `Citroen` because `np.std` return `NaN`:

```
print (maketotal_1[maketotal_1.index.get_level_values('Make') == 'Citroen '])
                                    Quantity
Month Model               Make              
11    Citroen C4 Aircross Citroen        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation... I figured out now. But, one thing which I noticed that the dataset has Citroen C4 Aircross...  when you write this code.. maketotal = df.pivot_table(values='Quantity',index=['Make','Model'],aggfunc='mean')... When I took the std. dev. , it dissepeared as nan values. Because expected output has Citroen C4.

Comment: @Bugs_Bunny - I also notice it. I think Reason is all values of std was `NaN`s.

Comment: @Bugs_Bunny - But I notice another problem. (I am not finacial guy, so not sure if understand it correct) so you need yearly fluctation. It means need `std` per months in each year? If yes, solution is correct.

Comment: To calculate fluctuation,  taking standart deviation of the yearly total sales for each model. Your solution is correct.

Comment: @Bugs_Bunny - Thank you for explanation. Btw,  you can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.